# How to study the quasi-concavity of a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following function:

```
f[y_] = y (k + h (1 - y - x) - t (1 - y - x) x + (1 - y) t (-y + x))
```

where k, h and t are parameters with values comprehended in the interval [0,1].
I already studied its concavity computing the second derivative wrt to y and using Reduce in order to understand when it is negative.

```
foc = D[f[y], y]
soc = D[foc, y]
Reduce[soc < 0]
```

Which gives the following output:

```
x \[Element] Reals && (t | y) \[Element] Reals && h > -t + 3 t y
```

I interpreted it as "the function is concave when `h > -t + 3 t y` (I do not understand the other part of the output).

Now, I would like to study under which conditions the function is quasi-concave. How can I do it?

Comment: So you are trying to show an inequality involving the function f... can you please tell us exactly what that inequality is? My first thought is to try Reduce to find the region over which the inequality holds.

Comment: Before approaching the quasi-concavity, I studied the concavity of the function. So, as you  said, I used Reduce in order to understand when the second derivative (wrt y, I forgot to say that the variable of interest is y, I will edit the post) is negative. Now I would like to study the quasi-concavity, which is a weaker condition than concavity, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: any conditions on `h`, `x` and `t`? (e.g., are they all positive reals?)

Comment: As said, h and t (together with k) range in the interval [0,1]. x can be any real number.

Comment: @kglr can you help me with this? I am really stuck :(

Comment: PlasticMan, posted an answer that seems to work for your `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First formalizing a textbook definition of *quasi-concavity* which gives us the desired condition for the case in OP:

```
ClearAll[quasiConcaveQ]
quasiConcaveQ[foo_] := Resolve[ForAll[{λ, y1, y2},
    0 < λ < 1 && Element[{y1, y2}, Reals], 
   foo[λ y1 + (1 - λ) y2] >= Min[foo[y1], foo[y2]]]]
```

For a cubic polynomial `a z + b z^2 + c z^3` (with `0<c<1`) this gives a simple condition:

```
FullSimplify[quasiConcaveQ[a # + b #^2 + c #^3 &], 0 < c < 1]
```

> ```
> 3 a c >= b^2
> ```

Defining `f` in OP in an alternative way:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[y_, k_, h_, t_, x_] := Collect[
    y (k + h (1 - y - x) - t (1 - y - x) x + (1 - y) t (-y + x)), y]

f[y, k, h, t, x]
```

> ```
>  (h + k - h x + t x^2) y + (-h - t) y^2 + t y^3
> ```

```
cRule = Thread[{a, b, c} ->  Rest[CoefficientList[Collect[f[y, k, h, t, x], y], y]]];

assumptions = And @@ Thread[0 < {k, h, t} < 1] && Element[{x}, Reals];

FullSimplify[FullSimplify[quasiConcaveQ[a # + b #^2 + c #^3 &], 0 < c < 1] /. 
  cRule, assumptions]
```

> ```
>  3 t (h + k - h x + t x^2) >= (h + t)^2
> ```

Comment: So, does it mean that f is quasi-concave when  3 t (h + k - h x + t x^2) >= (h + t)^2?

Comment: @PlasticMan, f is quasi-concave _when and only when_ `3 t (h + k - h x + t x^2) >= (h + t)^2`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the time you spent on this :)

Comment: Sorry to bother again. What if I have another function to study, for instance `r[x_] = k y + 1/2 (-2 + y) y (-t + y h) + k x + 
 1/2 x (-2 + 2 y + x) (-t + h x)`. How can I modify the code in order to study it?

Comment: @PlasticMan, since your new function is also cubic in `y`,  you can use `ClearAll[f]
f[y_, k_, h_, t_, x_] := 
 k y + 1/2 (-2 + y) y (-t + y h) + k x + 
  1/2 x (-2 + 2 y + x) (-t + h x);
cRule = Thread[{a, b, c} -> 
    Rest[CoefficientList[f[y, k, h, t, x], y]]];
FullSimplify[
 FullSimplify[quasiConcaveQ[a # + b #^2 + c #^3 &], 0 < c < 1] /. 
  cRule, assumptions]`

Comment: Even if this time I have a function of x?

Comment: sorry;  we need to change `cRule` to `cRule = Thread[{a, b, c} -> 
    Rest[CoefficientList[f[y, k, h, t, x], x]]];`

Comment: Ook, I thought so. However, the final condition is the same even after these considerations, so I don't know how to feel about it. Moreover, something strange happened. I got several numerical solutions, and I checked for which of them the conditions of concavity and quasi-concavity hold. Now, for all of them the concavity (concave down) is satisfied, whereas for none of them the quasi-concavity holds. This is strange, since concavity implies quasi-concavity. Is it possible that the quasi-concavity condition is wrong?